# preventing text from breaking to half

Tags: html, css

Here is what I mean

```css
h1 {
  color: grey;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  
  width: 100px;
}

h1 strong {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

h2 {
  color: grey;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  
  width: 200px;
}

h2 strong {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

h3 strong {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Dont want:<br>
  <strong>hello</strong>
  <strong>hello world</strong>
</h1>
<h2>
  Want:<br>
  <strong>hello</strong>
  <strong>hello world</strong>
</h2>
<h3>Basically i dont want "hello world" to break into 1 word, i want them to be <br><strong>hello world</strong><br> not <br><strong>hello<br>world</strong></h3>
```

i have made a codepen too: https://codepen.io/ivan-da-dev/pen/NWpvprr
as the above stated, i don't want my text to snap in half, if the text is too long for the parent, i want the whole  text to go to the text line, i don't want only 1 word to go to the next line

Answer (score 2):

Add a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` between the words.

```html
<p>
hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world 
hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world hello&nbsp;world 
</p>
vs.
<p>
hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world
hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this css property to the element you want to keep on one line
`white-space: nowrap`

```css
h1 {
  color: grey;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1 strong {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

h2 {
  color: grey;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  
  width: 200px;
}

h2 strong {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

h3 strong {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Dont want:<br>
  <strong>hello</strong>
  <strong>hello world</strong>
</h1>
<h2>
  Want:<br>
  <strong>hello</strong>
  <strong>hello world</strong>
</h2>
<h3>Basically i dont want "hello world" to break into 1 word, i want them to be <br><strong>hello world</strong><br> not <br><strong>hello<br>world</strong></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the option could be to modify your `h1` style as the following:

```css
h1 {
  color: grey;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

With `white-space: nowrap;` which prevents line break with space between words and `display: inline-block;` to match the style of your `h2` element, to wrap with background the length of the words, no the whole line block.

Comment: Why should OP modify their CSS for H1? Perhaps you should tell them why in your answer, it would more likely be up-voted with a clear and concise explanation along with code.

Comment: Good point @dalelandry, edited my answer above.